# how to get sharpsnmp device simulator discovered by SNMP managers?

Tags: c#, snmp, agent, sharp-snmp

I am trying to develop a device simulator to be tested against SNMP managers during development.
It can already host objects and with their OIDs, I can already perform GET and SET for each object using an MIB browser, but what I am trying to find out is,

are there certain objects / properties i need to host in order to be discovered by SNMP managers? 
Lets say I am trying to simulate a router SNMP agent. What do i need in order to make the SNMP manager 'see'/'discover' my 'device' as a router? Is there a standard way of doing it for SNMP managers? thanks

I am using C# and sharpsnmp tritonmate (8.0) .

Comment: [SNMP RFCs](http://www.snmp.com/protocol/snmp_rfcs.shtml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what algorithm the manager software uses to detect the device.

The snmpd sample in #SNMP can be discovered by the corresponding snmpdiscover sample, which demonstrates a common approach to detect SNMP agents over IPv4. However, not all manager software uses the same approach. The SNMP RFC documents do not define an official way.